# Ionic 2 with bluetooth barcode scanner as keyboard truncating data

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, barcode

I have an Ionic 2 app and a bluetooth barcode scanner. I am connecting the scanner to my android device as a standard keyboard device. When I open up any other app on the device like chrome or notepad and set the focus on the text area, then scan a barcode the full barcode(the ones I am testing with are about 10 alphanumberic characters ) is placed in the text area. When I try the same thing om my ionic app in a text input field only the first two or three characters are shown in the text area. The ode for my text area is:

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-input type="text" placeholder="input text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Anyone else ever had this issue. I am really stuck with how to deal with this?? I am not using the BLE or Bluetooth Serial plugins. As far as I am aware I should be able to do a simple connection like this. As I mentioned the connection works fine in the other apps on my android device.

Comment: What ionic version do you use? Be sure are using @latestversion.

Comment: I am running ionic 3.19.1

Comment: Have updated now running ionic-angular@3.9.1

Comment: When I scan the same barcode it works unpredicatably, sometime returning 2 characters sometimes 3 and sometimes 4 characters

Comment: But it works reliably in other app on my phone

Comment: I have discovered that if I go to GENERAL MANAGEMENT -> LANGUAGE AND INPUT -> PHYSICAL KEYBOARD ->SHOW VIRTUAL KEYBOARD and switch it off, then the scanning a barcode from the external bluetooth scanner whcih connects as a keybaord works perfectly. Very odd. This is not a solution for me anyway as I cant tell my app users to disable this keyboard as it wont work then for any other apps. Also tried doing keyboard.hide() but this removes the focus from the input element so I cant then use the scanner to capture input

Comment: Whats also interesting is that this works 100% when I test it in an ionic 1 app